# Find a file with the same name in multiple folders that can be anything

Tags: batch-file

Okay, so I have the code

```
cd ..
cd servers

for /d %%i in (*) do (
    cd logs
    findstr /R 76561*  "*_MA_output_log.txt" >> "..\..\..\tools\pre-results.txt"
)
```

However, this code doesn't seem to work the way I want it to- that is to say, it does not find the file in the log folder. The directories are structured pretty simply: its `..\servers\(something)\logs`and the code itself is in `..\tools`

I have researched a bit before asking here, and thats where I got the for loop from but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you read the command usage information by entering `For /?` at the Command Prompt?

Comment: @Compo I have updated my code, any suggestions? It still won't work

Answer (score 0):

This code works

```
cd "%~dp0\..\servers"
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b /a:d') do (
    if exist "%%A\logs" (
        echo Found logs folder, switching directories...
        pushd "%%A\logs"
        if exist "*_MA_output_log.txt" (
            echo Found file, executing code
            findstr /R 76561*  "*_MA_output_log.txt" >> "..\..\..\tools\pre-results.txt"
            goto Parse
        ) else (
            echo MultiAdmin output does not exist!
            goto End
        )
        popd
    ) else (
        echo Logs folder not found!
        goto End
    )
)
```

Comment: Not related to your original problem but if you are looking for `76561` anywhere in the line then the asterisk is not needed and in fact it can give you wrong results ; for instance `76562` will also match . Because you've made `1` optional by `1*`